# ¿Como puedo agregar la función if de python?

Tags: python

Soy principiante y debe estar la siguiente información.
Si el nombre del animal es uno diferente a jirafa,elefante o chimpancé debe decir que el animal es desconocido y es parte de las instrucciones el usar la sentencia if y un bucle, ya sea for o while. Y no se donde ubicar dichos requerimientos para que funcione bien esto es lo que tengo.

```
#se inicia solicitanto el nombre del animal
print("Escriba el nombre del animal")
animal = input()

#se solicita el número o cantidad de animales
print(f"Ingrese la cantidad de {animal} de 0 a 1 año");
uno = int(input())
print(f"Ingrese la cantidad de {animal} de 2 años");
dos = int(input())

print(f"Ingrese la cantidad de {animal} de 3 años o mas");
tres = int(input())

total = uno+dos+tres;

#se muestra el porcentaje de animales de cada edad
print(f"Total de {animal} es: " + str(total));
print("el porcentaje de animales de 0 a 1 año es :" + str((uno/total)*100) );
print("el porcentaje de animales de 2 años es :" + str((dos/total)*100) );
print("el porcentaje de animales de 3 años o mas es: " + str((tres/total)*100) )
```

Comment: Si tienes un arreglo como: `animales = ["jirafa", "elefante", "chimpancé"]` con los animales permitidos, para saber si la entrada no se encuentra en esa lista: `if animal not in animales:`. Lo que no me queda claro es para qué necesitas un ciclo. ¿Te pidieron hacer el chequeo de si se encuentra o no en la lista, a través de in ciclo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrias crear una *Lista* de animales conocidos y el bucle *While* para que solicite nuevamente introducir un animal, en caso que introduzcan un animal que no este en la *Lista* de animales conocidos, algo como esto:

```py
animales_conocidos = ["jirafa", "elefante","chimpancé"]
while True:
    #se inicia solicitanto el nombre del animal
    print("Escriba el nombre del animal")
    animal = input()
    if animal in animales_conocidos:
        #se solicita el número o cantidad de animales
        print(f"Ingrese la cantidad de {animal} de 0 a 1 año");
        uno = int(input())
        print(f"Ingrese la cantidad de {animal} de 2 años");
        dos = int(input())

        print(f"Ingrese la cantidad de {animal} de 3 años o mas");
        tres = int(input())

        total = uno+dos+tres;

        #se muestra el porcentaje de animales de cada edad
        print(f"Total de {animal} es: " + str(total));
        print("el porcentaje de animales de 0 a 1 año es :" + str((uno/total)*100) );
        print("el porcentaje de animales de 2 años es :" + str((dos/total)*100) );
        print("el porcentaje de animales de 3 años o mas es: " + str((tres/total)*100) )
        break
    else:
        print(f"El animal {animal} es desconocido. Por favor introduzca uno conocido")
        continue
```

Nota:

- Con el operador *in* compruebas si el animal introducido esta dentro de la *Lista* de animales conocido.
- La declaración *Break* la usas para romper el Bucle y evitar que sea infinito al finalizar el calculo de porcentaje
- La declaración *continue* la usas para detener la iteración actual y continuar con la siguiente iteración del Bucle, pero... en este caso no es del todo necesaria porque en Python una vez el Bucle recorre todas las líneas de código este continua con la siguiente iteración. Sin embargo, pienso que es una buena practica ponerlo.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias!!! Me funcionó perfecctamente, de verdad gracias